# How to handle HTTP authentication using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection

I'm writing a Java client that POSTs to a HTTP server that requires **authentication**.
I have to support at least the following three authentication methods: Basic, Digest or Negotiate. Additionally the POST may be very large (over 2MB), so I need to use streaming. 
As is documented for [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int))

> When output streaming is enabled, authentication and redirection cannot be handled automatically. A HttpRetryException will be thrown when reading the response if authentication or redirection are required.

So, I need to handle authentication myself. I searched, and searched again, for a way to employ the, already coded, classes - but found no way...

I could just pluck the needed sources from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/f7afe7a5e086/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/) (as they are GPLv2 with Classpath exception). Is this the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: what sort of authentication? HTTP BASIC Auth? Or something more complex?

Comment: Either _Basic_, _Digest_ or _Negotiate_. Basic is **easy**. The other two are not :)

Answer (score 49):

Do you need output streaming? The `HttpURLConnection` most definitely supports authentication with the `Authenticator` class, see: [Http Authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html).

**Update:** In case the `Authenticator` is not an option, you can manually do HTTP basic authentication by adding an extra header to your HTTP request. Try the following code (untested):

```
String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes());
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
uc.connect();
```

Comment: Yes. My **POST** includes a file which may well be over 2MB in size.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to clarify that I need to handle either Basic, Digest or Negotiate authentication.
What I really need help with is _Negotiate_

Comment: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is JVM dependant. A better option would probably be using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 from Apache.

Comment: Related to @Mat's comment: on Android, you'll want to use `Base64.encodeToString()` ([code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7360440/56285)).

Comment: What is the process with Https will this also work ?

Comment: I have error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header value: Basic YTFkOWY2ZjkzMzE2NDA2OTljYzA3ZjJkYzkyYTQ0Yjk6azF3bjFFelJ1RkdPeGdicnVtTk83b0Ft0pjVW1BV0ljVTFmK2pNbmpLcz0=
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.checkMessageHeader(HttpURLConnection.java:482)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.isExternalMessageHeaderAllowed(HttpURLConnection.java:434)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:2753)

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Related to @Mat's comment :

Here is an example used by my team and I :

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(endpoint);
getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + getBasicAuthenticationEncoding());

private String getBasicAuthenticationEncoding() {

        String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes()));
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: My Eclipse didn't find the codec package, but you can directly download it from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi and add the jar as reference!