# How to avoid JVM opening auth window when HttpURLConnection hits 401

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, basic-authentication

I am using `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, and it annoyingly presents a window asking for username and password whenever a 401 response code is returned by the HTTP server.

How can I get rid of this automatic auth dialog? I want to handle 401s myself.

I tried `setAllowUserInteraction(false)`, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: perhaps this may help - plug in your own Authenticator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection

Comment: That did the trick! Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Answer posted.

Comment: This happens for me when running under Web Start on both Linux (OpenJDK 7) and Windows (Java 8), but not when running via OpenJDK `java` normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup comes from the default authenticator. To remove the popup, you can plug in your own authenticator. See [How to handle HTTP authentication using HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection)

Answer (score 1):

[@mdma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249612/3004881) is correct, you can plug in your own `Authenticator` to handle authentication, so that there's no popup.

If you're already handling authentication in another way (such as by `connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", ...)`, as [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4883890/3004881) describes), you can use [`Authenticator.setDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html#setDefault-java.net.Authenticator-) to choose to *not* to use any `Authenticator` for authentication:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(null);
```

This removes the old default `Authenticator`, so that if your authentication is wrong, you get the error response code via your `URLConnection`, without opening any popup.

---

An equivalent way is to set the default to an `Authenticator` which returns `null` for `getPasswordAuthentication()` (which is the default implementation), as in the following code:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() { });
```

But unless you're going to add code to your `Authenticator`, I don't see a reason to choose this over `null`.