# Does anyone know how to decode and encode a string in Base64 using Base64?

Tags: java, android, base64

I am using the following code, but it's not working.

```
String source = "password"; 
byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16"); 
Base64 bs = new Base64(); 
//bs.encodeBytes(byteArray); 
System.out.println(bs.encodeBytes(byteArray)); 
//bs.decode(bs.encodeBytes(byteArray));
System.out.println(bs.decode(bs.encodeBytes(byteArray)));
```

Comment: You must import this `import android.util.Base64;` and then can use `Base64.encodeToString` & `Base64.decode` according to your needs

Answer (score 559, accepted):

First:

- Choose an encoding. UTF-8 is generally a good choice; stick to an encoding which will definitely be valid on both sides. It would be rare to use something other than UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Transmitting end:

- Encode the string to bytes (e.g. `text.getBytes(encodingName)`)
- Encode the bytes to base64 using the `Base64` class
- Transmit the base64

Receiving end:

- Receive the base64
- Decode the base64 to bytes using the `Base64` class
- Decode the bytes to a string (e.g. `new String(bytes, encodingName)`)

So something like:

```
// Sending side
byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Receiving side
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Or with `StandardCharsets`:

```
// Sending side
byte[] data = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Receiving side
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: can you give me exact code that would be great help. i am using but its not working. String source = "password";
     byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16");
     Base64 bs = new Base64();
     //bs.encodeBytes(byteArray);
     System.out.println( bs.encodeBytes(byteArray));
      
     
     //bs.decode(bs.encodeBytes(byteArray));
    System.out.println(bs.decode(bs.encodeBytes(byteArray)));

Comment: @max: "It's not working" is never a good description of what's happening. Will edit my post though.

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't call static methods as if they're instance methods...

Comment: if you put it like that it will work String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);

Comment: You should be careful using this answer. You really should handle the  UnsupportedEncodingException. So surround this answer with try-catch.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder: Absolutely not. `UTF-8` is guaranteed to be a valid encoding in Java: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html. Admittedly these days I'd specify `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead. I've updated the answer to specify that you should be confident in the presence of the charset, but I'd pretty much *always* use UTF-8.

Comment: When I use Base64.DEFAULT then it says bad base64. So use Base64.URL_SAFE and enjoyee

Comment: @AndroidHelp: No, use the right version for your context. If you want to put the data into a URL, then sure, use `URL_SAFE`. But if you're *not* putting it in a URL, it's better to use the default one, as that complies with the more common encoding.

Comment: in my case add header not in url Base64.NO_WRAP !)

Answer (score 30):

For **Kotlin** mb better to use this:

```
fun String.decode(): String {
    return Base64.decode(this, Base64.DEFAULT).toString(charset("UTF-8"))
}

fun String.encode(): String {
    return Base64.encodeToString(this.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

Example:

```
Log.d("LOGIN", "TEST")
Log.d("LOGIN", "TEST".encode())
Log.d("LOGIN", "TEST".encode().decode())
```

Comment: Naming for these extensions functions is horrible. I would highly recommend using encodeToBase64 or something similar.

Comment: They are absolutely not clear and obvious. Tell me: what means "decode" or "encode"? There are thousands of decoding/encoding algorithms... What if you need Base64 and Hex? How would you name the methods then?

Comment: Not to mention the different Base64 standards out there.

Comment: Clear and obvious for this use case. If i need another algorithm i will never use it as extension method.

Comment: Nevertheless I would prefer something like: 'toBase64()' and 'fromBase64()' as a minimum. This way I don't need to read any documentation to know what the method will do. Keep in mind: "code is read more than it is written".

Comment: Yes, if i want to emphasize encoding and algorithm i will name it like toBase64UTF8(), but i don't need it, simple is better. Naming is one of the major problem in development. Please vote down on this answer and we close this dicussion, thanks.

Comment: So much fuss for an example :)

Answer (score 20):

To anyone else who ended up here while searching for info on how to decode a string encoded with `Base64.encodeBytes()`, here was my solution:

```
// encode
String ps = "techPass";
String tmp = Base64.encodeBytes(ps.getBytes());

// decode
String ps2 = "dGVjaFBhC3M=";
byte[] tmp2 = Base64.decode(ps2); 
String val2 = new String(tmp2, "UTF-8");
```

Also, I'm supporting older versions of Android so I'm using Robert Harder's Base64 library from http://iharder.net/base64

Answer (score 12):

If you are using **Kotlin** than use like this

For Encode

```
val password = "Here Your String"
val data = password.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
val base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

For Decode

```
val datasd = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT)
val text = String(datasd, charset("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Or you can use Charsets.UTF_8 instead of charset("UTF-8").

Comment: @makovkastar just confirm, now StandardCharsets.UTF_8

Answer (score 7):

something like

```
String source = "password"; 
byte[] byteArray;
try {
    byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16");
    System.out.println(new String(Base64.decode(Base64.encode(byteArray,
           Base64.DEFAULT), Base64.DEFAULT)));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your answer implies that encoding passwords in base64 is a good practice. In fact it is NOT as anyone can simply decode it.

Answer (score 6):

To encrypt:

```
byte[] encrpt= text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(encrpt, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

To decrypt:

```
byte[] decrypt= Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(decrypt, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

'java.util.Base64' class provides functionality to encode and decode the information in Base64 format.

**How to get Base64 Encoder?**

```
Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
```

**How to get Base64 Decoder?**

```
Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
```

**How to encode the data?**

```
Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
String originalData = "java";
byte[] encodedBytes = encoder.encode(originalData.getBytes());
```

**How to decode the data?**

```
Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(encodedBytes);
String decodedStr = new String(decodedBytes);
```

You can get more details at this [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2018/03/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-java.html).

Comment: This might result in ClassNotFoundException on certain devices. Imo you should use android.util.Base64 instead (assuming we're in an android context, based on labels).

Answer (score 2):

Above many answers that don't work for me, and some of them are no exception handling in the correct way. here am adding a perfect solution that works amazing for me sure also for you too.

```
//base64 decode string 
 String s = "ewoic2VydmVyIjoic2cuenhjLmx1IiwKInNuaSI6InRlc3RpbmciLAoidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0
    ZXIiLAoicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJ0ZXN0ZXIiLAoicG9ydCI6IjQ0MyIKfQ==";
    String val = a(s) ;
     Toast.makeText(this, ""+val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
       public static String a(String str) {
             try {
                 return new String(Base64.decode(str, 0), "UTF-8");
             } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalArgumentException unused) {
                 return "This is not a base64 data";
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answers I'm using the following utility methods in case anyone would like to use it.

```
    /**
 * @param message the message to be encoded
 *
 * @return the enooded from of the message
 */
public static String toBase64(String message) {
    byte[] data;
    try {
        data = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String base64Sms = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return base64Sms;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @param message the encoded message
 *
 * @return the decoded message
 */
public static String fromBase64(String message) {
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(message, Base64.DEFAULT);
    try {
        return new String(data, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For API level 26+

```
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
```

Ref:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString(byte[])

Answer (score 1):

Answer from 2021 in Kotlin.

Encode :

```
val data: String = "Hello"
val dataByteArray: ByteArray = data.toByteArray()
val dataInBase64: String = Base64Utils.encode(dataByteArray)
```

Decode :

```
val dataInBase64: String = "..."
val dataByteArray: ByteArray = Base64Utils.decode(dataInBase64)
val data: String = dataByteArray.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you! Just accessing Base64.getEncoder is not available on if your API minimum is set to < 26!

Answer (score 0):

```
package net.itempire.virtualapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;
TextView textView4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        textView2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        textView3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        textView4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             textView2.setText(Base64.encodeToString(editText.getText().toString().getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        });

        textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView4.setText(new String(Base64.decode(textView2.getText().toString(),Base64.DEFAULT)));

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for android API `byte[]` to `Base64String` encoder

```
byte[] data=new byte[];
String Base64encodeString=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: note, this is outdated, I think since Android API 26. use `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data)` instead

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity">
   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/edt"
       android:paddingTop="30dp"
       />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:text="Encode"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:text="decode"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"


        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is for to encode and dcode through base64 in android studio

Comment: Please update your comment in answer. Also post Java and XML in single answer.

Comment: Writing some explanation along with some code is always a good practice. Thanks!