# How to pass String portably?

Tags: java, android

I want to encode some value and pass it to the server. My concern is will my secret key be portable to the server side? For encode I want to get bytes as MyString.getBytes(), but server can keep Strings in a different way, so when he try to decode my message the result will be wrong.

Could you tell me please a right way how to make strings portable, independent from platforms?

Comment: Why wouldn't the String be "portable" if you use identical encryption/decryption and encoding on each end..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For portability, you should use String.getBytes(Charset) and the corresponding constructor. You need to specify the same charset on the client and the server. If you don't specify a charset when encoding/decoding strings to bytes the result depends on the default charset of the platform and is therefore not portable.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use Base64 Encoding/Decoding formula. [here's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) the introduction for the BASE64 for android.

and [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code) to encode/decode.