# Need to send image and text to the server

Tags: php, android, http

In my application I need to send image and the note(text of 180) characters to the server.

Now am able to send image and text separately but I need to send together now.

What would be the approach?

Currently am sending image using thread.

```
// open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://xxx.com/image.php");

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
                // conn.setRequestProperty("id", imei);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file; filename="
                        + fileName + imei + lineEnd);


                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            File delfile = new File(currentfile);
                            //delfile.delete();
                        }
                    });
                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                // dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                // dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "upload failed Please, try after some time ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            // dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
```

For sending text am using simple http post method.

I need this for my application where we are going to take snapshot and type some thing in edittext box and send.

Comment: you should use Httpclient with HttpPost and MultipartEntity to send MIME type data along with text.

Comment: am using httpclient,httpcore,mime4j,apachehttpclient jar files but still getting error for multipart entity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, You need this [org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachehttpcomponentshttpclient421jar.htm) jar file and import to your build path.

You can do that in such a way. consider the following

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

And the declaration :

```
 private List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

private HttpURLConnection connection = null;
private DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
private String twoHyphens = "--";
private String boundary = "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
```

And the source code is as follows :

```
try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(StickerToSend);
            URL url = new URL("Your URL");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   // Here you can add parameters as follows :

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    // The keyword "type" is the key value and 

            outputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\""
                            + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // You can assign values as like follows : 

            outputStream.writeBytes("Your value");
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"sticker\";filename=\""
                            + StickerToSend + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.d("The server response message ", " Server Response"
                    + serverResponseMessage);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            // retrieve the response from server
            int ch;
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                b.append((char) ch);
            }
            String result = b.toString();
            Log.i("Response", result);

            JSONObject jsonobject;
            try {
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
                boolean isPosted = jsonobject.getJSONObject("response")
                        .getString("httpCode").equals("200") ? true : false;

                if (isPosted)
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(POST_SUCCESS);
                else
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(POST_FAILURE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("the xceptions ",
                        "Xcep in posting status messages are : "
                                + e.getMessage());
            }
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Xceptions",
                    "Xceptions are  upload video file  " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

This piece of code really works very well. I have checked this also. Please feel free if there is any issues.

Comment: Here it is, `outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"your params name\""+ lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Your value");`

Comment: StickerToSend is the file name. I am sending a file and a text to server.
`outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"your param name\""+ lineEnd);
   outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
   outputStream.writeBytes("add your value here");`

Comment: Can u explain, where is second parameter adding you?

Comment: What is meaning of `writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);` ? Where to start and where to end? can u explain me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoder for encoding image to string ([Base 64 encode and decode example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code)) and make a web service to send this to server. So in that web service you can add multiple inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try this may helps you

```
public void WSCall(final String filePath, final String textTosend) {

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.com/image.php");
            StringBody data = new StringBody(textTosend, Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8));
            MultiPartEntity entity = new MultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("uploaded_file", new FileBody(new File(filePath), "image/png"));
            entity.addPart("text", data);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse WSresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (Throwable e) {

        }

    }
```