# Android - How to upload video/image to PHP Server

Tags: java, php, android, web-services

I am able to post string values to PHP server by using the following code:

```
 public void callWebService(String strEmailList){
    HttpResponse response = null;
    String responseBody="";
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringkey1",
            String_Value1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringkey2", String_Value2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringkey3", String_Value3));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringkey4", String_Value4));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringkey5", String_Value5));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringkey6", Here i need to post Image));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://MY URL");

        if (nameValuePairs != null)
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    handleResponse(responseBody);
}
```

I am getting `responseBody` perfectly if i post only string values. In the `nameValuePair`, I need to post Image to Server. Can anyone help me how to post image using following code.

Comment: Check this out It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828578/need-to-send-image-and-text-to-the-server/19828801#19828801

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send image to the server as a Multipart entity

```
public void upload(String filepath) throws IOException
    {
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
     File file = new File(filepath);
     MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
     ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
     mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile); 
     httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
     System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             // check the response and do what is required
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For uploading image and Video,,, you need to use MultiPart.First you need to Attach your file in fileBody which later attach in Multipart

```
public JSONObject file_upload1(String URL, String userid, String topic_id,
        String topicname, String filelist, String taglist,
        String textComment, String textLink) {
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

        FileBody bin = null;
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            File file = new File(filelist);

            try {
                bin = new FileBody(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            reqEntity.addPart("post_data" + i, bin);

        reqEntity.addPart("tag", new StringBody("savetopicactivities"));
        reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(userid));
        reqEntity.addPart("text", new StringBody(textComment));
        reqEntity.addPart("count",
                new StringBody(String.valueOf(taglist.size())));
        reqEntity.addPart("topic_id", new StringBody(topic_id));
        reqEntity.addPart("topic_name", new StringBody(topicname));
        reqEntity.addPart("link", new StringBody(textLink));

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        json = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("json   " + json);
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        MultipartEntity entity = new  MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        for (int index = 0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) 
        {
            if (index == nameValuePairs.size()-1) 
            {
                entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(),
                        new FileBody(new File(nameValuePairs.get(index)
                                .getValue())));
            } else {

                    entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName() , new                                        StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));
                }


            }

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) 
        {
            String resdata = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            System.out.println("DATA :" + resdata);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: add httpmime-4.2.1.jar into your project