# Android HTTP Post File

Tags: php, android, http-post

Currently I have an Android app that does http post of data to a webserver which has a php script to receive the data and save into a text file.

Below are the code snippets:

Android:

```
 public void postData(String id, String data) {
       
         // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("<server_ip>/phppost.php");

         try {
             // Add your data
             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", data));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

             // Execute HTTP Post Request
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }
}
```

php script:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$file = $id . ".txt";
$data = $_POST['stringdata'];
file_put_contents($file, $data);

?>
```

But this is for data and it could work without any issue. How do I do the same for a file? Meaning a *.mp3 or *.txt files. How do I http post files and how do I modify the php script to receive the files?

Comment: Please check this [Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828578/need-to-send-image-and-text-to-the-server/19828801#19828801)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                             + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                              +"Your/service/url"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }
```

And invoke that function like

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                      //Show information to user that file is uploading
                                    }
                                });                      

                             uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
```

And don`t forget to add permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: link only answers are discouraged. While the link may answer the question it is preferable to add the content of the link to your post.

Comment: Its doesn't matter whether the answer contains without content. Its only matter is that answer should point to right direction.

Comment: read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144566/new-policy-on-link-only-answers. gain enough reputation then you post links as comments

Comment: and this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168712/what-is-stack-overflows-take-on-link-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_FILES){
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$fileContents = file_get_contents($file["tmp_name"]);
//check whether  target dir exist then put contents
if (!is_dir("path"));
file_put_contents("../../uploads/3/dbbackups/".$_FILES['file']['name'], $fileContents);
}
```