# Send image and text to server pc

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I'm building an app which requires sending of image along with 2 text fields from app to server pc.

I followed this example :

[Upload file to server](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

It works perfectly.
But this example shows only uploading of image. 
I want to send text from 2 edit texts along with the image.

What changes needs to be done in java source as well as php code?

Comment: Please check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828578/need-to-send-image-and-text-to-the-server/19828801#comment34553438_19828801)

Comment: How to retrieve text value in php?

Comment: retrieved using $_POST[]. It worked..Thanks. but the only problem is now that image uploaded is corrupted

Comment: what do you mean by corrupted?

Comment: problem solved...actually there was an error in php file

Comment: thats cool, upvote the answer which helped you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To send data over server you can use JSON Parsing and PHP to forward data from activity to websever
Simple example is [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: I know how to send data using JSON parsing and php thing, But I want to know how to send image along with the data

Comment: You can implement by using AsyncTask class doInBackground() method.  add both code in this method and you can then send both images and data too..