# Encode and decode html with base64 android

Tags: android

I am new to android and wants to encode and decode html page using base64 and save html page in memory card.If any one can help me its great support for me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Android's `Base64` class. The documentation is here:

- [Base64 class on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

It has obviously named methods that you can use very easily:

- [encode(byte[], int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte[],%20int))
- [decode(String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20int))

---

For more information, there is no way I can improve on the excellent Jon Skeet in this link.

- [Base 64 encode and decode example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7360440/383414)

---

Here is his example code:

```
// Sending side
byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Receiving side
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```