# How do i get bitmap image from inputstream(base64 String) in android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, inputstream

How do I get a bitmap image from `InputStream(base64 String)` in Android?

Below is my code:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Bitmap image;
    URL url1 = null;
    try {
        url1 = new URL("http://sunnyfacemash.atwebpages.com/get.php"); // url 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
         image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());
         return image;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        image = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: just opened your php url in browser it is displaying some string is it base64 string?

Comment: yes it is a base64 string. i want to get that string and display picture in android.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code) answer contains both conversion string to base and vice versa

Answer (score -1):

Download stream to string, then use `Base64.decode` on it and feed this to `BitmapFactory`.

Use `ByteArrayInputStream` for factory