# Base64 are removing dots from string

Tags: java, android, base64

I am trying to transform a string to byte and then get again as string, but the result was different. Have a look:

To decode:

```
byte[] tokenInBytes = Base64.decode(token, mFlags);
mTokenPreference.put(Base64.encodeToString(tokenInBytes, mFlags));
```

To get like a string again:

```
String value = Base64.encodeToString(tokenInBytes, mFlags);
```

The original string (before decode): `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhMDA2ZTI4OGQ4ZDc1Z`

And after was (after encode): `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJpZCI6IjVhMDA2ZTI4OGQ4ZDc1Z`

Dots was removed. Anyone knows what I did wrong?

The value of mFlags was:

```
int mFlags = Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING;
```

Comment: Put the original string in your code in order to make a reproducable post.

Comment: `trying to transform to byte `. What is it that you are trying to transform to byte?

Comment: @greenapps I'm sorry. I edited post.

Comment: `Put the original string in your code in order to make a reproducable post`. Why didnt you take the effort to do so?

Comment: `transform a string to byte `. Which string? And what does it contain? Please write a clear post!

Comment: @greenapps `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhMDA2ZTI4OGQ4ZDc1Z`, I put this in post.

Comment: Yes you already told that. Dont repeat yourself. But use it in your code. You are not using it in your code are you!? Assing it to token to begin with. That is what i asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your string value (dot) with any letter then after encode and decode replace same letter with dot.

Answer (score 0):

I got this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code) link

```
// Sending side
byte[] data = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Receiving side
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String value = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: @RafaelaLourenço as it a special character  i think you should do like this
String encodeStr =URLEncoder.encode( yourstring, "UTF-8" );
// Sending side
byte[] data = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(encodeStr, Base64.DEFAULT);
// Receiving side
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String value = new String(data, "UTF-8");
String decodeString = URLDecoder.decode( value, "UTF-8" );