# Common encryption for a web app - how to?

Tags: java, android, encryption

We are trying to use common encryption for Mobile and Java Web app. Tried out several methods. But the data we encrypt in mobile doesn't get decrypted properly in web and vice versa.

In Android, we are getting an exception saying that the getEncoder and detDecoder methods are supported only for versions greater than API 26. (Oreo). Please help.

```
public class TestCrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String secretKey = "bHappy";

        String originalString = "vidhu";
        String encryptedString = AES.encrypt(originalString, secretKey) ;
        String decryptedString = AES.decrypt(encryptedString, secretKey) ;

        System.out.println("originalString ====  "+originalString);
        System.out.println("encryptedString ==== "+encryptedString);
        System.out.println("decryptedString ==== "+decryptedString);
    }

}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author vidya HP
 */
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void setKey(String myKey)
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: so either use api > 26 or use `android.util.Base64`

Comment: we are using android.util.Base64, but still its not working. We tried php vs android too. Is it a little endian big endian problem?

Comment: why just not using https?

Comment: `getting an exception saying that the getEncoder and detDecoder methods` for encoding you may have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code