# Base 64 Encoding Decoding for iOS in Multiplatform Kotlin

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on an iOS app, which uses multiplatform Kotlin. I need to encode/decode a string into base64. I am able to encode a normal string with below code, but I am not able to decode a base 64 string into normal string. Below is my code.

```
fun encodeToBase64()  {
    var st: NSString = "normalString"
    var data: NSData? = st.dataUsingEncoding(encoding = 
    NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    if (data != null) {
        var str = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(options = 0)
        println("base 64 string == $str")
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: check this out.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code/7360440

Comment: @Jaydeep, that link has answers for Android only, I need to do this for iOS as well using multiplatform Kotlin.

Comment: there are some answers which works for kotlin as well..

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still looking for base64 encoding and decoding and/or hashing in multiplatform projects. The Okio library has multiplatform support and can be used as a kotlin native solution. (https://square.github.io/okio/multiplatform/)

```
fun shar256(input: String): String? = input.encodeUtf8().sha256()

 fun base64Encoded(input: String): String? = input.encodeUtf8().base64()

 fun base64Decoded(input: String): String? = input.decodeBase64()?.utf8()
```