# Eclipse plugin dev, how to stop HttpsURLConnection of poping up user/password window when I connect

Tags: java, httpsurlconnection

JDK IBM 1.6
Eclipse 3.6.2

Connect to a server with following code.

> URL urlTemplate = new URL(uri); uc = (HttpURLConnection)
>   urlTemplate.openConnection();

when connecting with wrong credential, it will pop up a window to enter correct credential as input, how to stop it? it seems to be built-in action and unable to stop that build-in functionality.

Another issue is that, when i connected successfully to server once, it will store the credentials and subsequent tests will all be working even though with wrong user/password. How to clear the cache, so it can test new input user and password?

Comment: The popup comes from the default authenticator. To remove the popup, you can plug in your own authenticator. Refer below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection Thanks

Comment: Thanks Hariharan. After replace authenticator, it works, no window pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup comes from the default authenticator. To remove the popup, you can plug in your own authenticator.

Refer below link

[How to handle HTTP authentication using HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection)