# Java and HttpURLConnection not sending data

Tags: java, netbeans, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get `HttpURLConnection` to post a JSON string to a PHP file remotely. It's not working no matter what I do. This is my current code:

```
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL('http://domain.com/me.php').openConnection()));
                            httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
                            httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                            httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            httpcon.connect();

                            String initial = "{'out': '" + idir + prod + ".jpg', 'in': '" + item[3] + "'}";
                            byte[] outputBytes = initial.getBytes("UTF-8");

                            OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
                            os.write(outputBytes);

                            os.close();
```

I know that the `initial` string contains data, I have run a `System.out.println` on it and the `outputBytes` variables and both have contents.

I know it's not posting because I have the PHP file set to save posted contents to a file locally. No file is ever created when running it.

I know the PHP side of things work and the server accepts posts as I can run this just fine:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{'value': 7.5}" "http://domain.com/me.php"
```

And it works fine creating the file and writing post content to output file.

**EDIT**

Ok, after printing the responses I'm now getting a 401 code, unauthorized. I'm using Apache HTPASSWD authentication, but I was passing the user and pass in the URL as `http://user:pass@domain.com/me.php`. This worked from curl from the CLI, so I thought it would work here also, evidently it does not.

So how do I authenticate using HttpURLConnection?

Comment: I forgot to mention, it is within a `try` and `catch` but no exceptions come up.

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: I don't think the code is grabbing a response and printing it. How would I print a response so I can post here?

Comment: There's a `getResponseCode` method. You can also `getInputStream` or `getErrorStream` to see if there was a response body.

Comment: This might be useless... but, how do you know that the PHP parses well your JSON when you are passing another JSON object to test it?

Comment: @luanjot At this point it doesn't matter wether PHP parses correctly or not. The fact of the matter is PHP isn't even creating the file on calling it from a url. The file write method of PHP is called at the very top before anything, heck I can call the PHP file from a URL bar in a browser and get an empty file created. So the fact is that no matter what PHP is doing Java is never making a connection to the file, hence where the problem lies.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok, I'm getting a 401 code, unauthorized. I'm using Apache HTPASSWD authentication, but I was passing the user and pass in the URL as `http://user:pass@domain.com/me.php`. This works from curl from the CLI, so I thought it would work here also, evidently it does not. So how do I authenticate using `HttpURLConnection`?

Comment: You should update your question with those details. I don't know how but I'm sure there are some related questions/answers around here.

Comment: can you add this header in your PHP:
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

Comment: @NVBhargava No, that doesn't fix it, sorry.

Comment: Try using an authenticator in your Java class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up basic authentication. You can do it through plain Java or using Apache HttpClient.

[How to handle HTTP authentication using HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection)

http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication