# Failed HTTP in redmain using get request

Tags: java, authentication

I started bitnami's iso on vmware machine.
Standard administration login and pass for bitnami is :
login: user,
pass: bitnami.

In Authentication tab is selected Authentication required, Enable REST web service and enable JSONP support.

Any body knows, why I get below statement?
For any help i will be very grateful.

I got a statement :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP
error code : 401 at NetClientGet.main(NetClientGet.java:36)
Java Result: 1
```

My code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.78/issues.json?key=pjxjDvD9ez0Qm97iApka");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP status code [401](http://httpstatus.es/401) means you have an authentication problem. That has nothing to do with your code.

However throwing a RuntimeException for a bad status code is rough.

```
if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
}
```

Maybe you can handle different scenarios gracefully. Example :

```
if (conn.getResponseCode() >= 300) {
  // Something unexpected happened
  System.out.println("Unexpected response from server");
  return // Stop here
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I did not read your code carefully. Given the status code you get, it seems you need to send an HTTP auth to your server. It would look like that :

```
String username = "user"
String password = "bitnami"
String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes());

URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.78/issues.json?key=pjxjDvD9ez0Qm97iApka");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Note : No promise that it will compile/work :)

Code taken from this SO thread : ["How to handle HTTP authentication using HttpURLConnection?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection)

Comment: i changed URL to URL url = new URL("http://user:bitnami@192.168.0.78/issues.json"); and i got 422 error :(. Never ending story :((. Do you have any idea??

Comment: @Karaban Are you suppose to send a parameter in order to get the list of issues? Because 422 means the request is syntactically correct, but semantically wrong. A missing parameter should not return a 422, but we never knows.