# MailChimp Integration in Java

Tags: java, rest, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I want to integrate MailChimp API in my java project. When I call Rest call using HttpURLConnection class, it responds with 401 code.

Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "apikey <my-key>");

String input = "<json data>";

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
//os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();

if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

String output;
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}

conn.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 4):

I will suggest using [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi) package for encoding.
It support various formats such as Base64 and Hexadecimal.

Earlier I was also facing the same issue. I am sharing the code that I used in my application for authenticating to Mailchimp API v-3.0

```
//basic imports
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
.
.
.
 //URL to access and Mailchimp API key 
String url = "https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/";
//mailchimp API key 
String apikey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

// Authentication PART

String name = "Anything over here!";
String password = apikey;     //Mailchimp API key
String authString = name + ":" + password;

byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

URL urlConnector = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)           urlConnector.openConnection();
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

InputStream is1 = httpConnection.getInputStream();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1, "utf-8"));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
br.close();
```

Now you can use StringBuilder Object **sb** to parse the output as required

Hope it resolves your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP [401 response code](https://httpstatuses.com/401) means "not authorized".

You didn't set or pass your credentials properly.  Is the certificate from the client set up?  Here's an [example](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/simple-https-example) of an HTTPS client.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes, I know the problem is in the way of passing api key. I checked the MailChimp api and they don't have any example on how to pass api key in Java to authorize.

Comment: It's HTTP, so my first guess would be to set the HTTP basic auth headers.

Comment: MailChimp API uses Basic Authentication. There are tons of java examples of that out in the world, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection).

Comment: I tried those things but still it returns with 401 status. I am not sure if I am missing anything for MailChimp api to pass.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 401 simply means you're **not Authorized** to send this request.

you can set **username** any string (the MailChimp docs suggest using `anystring` as a username) and your **API key as a password**.

In case of Postman request, you can set under the **Authorization** tab choose `Basic Auth` to set username and password. Below image shows the same.

[image]

More info about Adding/ Getting Members to/ from a Mailing List on MailChimp API 3.0, I find [this article](https://medium.com/@dddotcom/intro-to-mailchimp-api-3-0-adding-members-to-a-mailing-list-and-testing-with-postman-f056d900e0d9) very useful.