# URL GET request with parameters

Tags: java, android

For example I have this string:

```
String url = "http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD";
```

and I have the `String USERNAME="123456"` and `String PASSWORD="123";`
When I make the URL GET request how do I inject the USERNAME and PASSWORD into the URL?

Comment: Looks like you formed the correct URL. What issue or problem you are facing? Describe more.

Comment: I have a webservice with XML response, to get access to the response I need to pass a username and a password. I don't not know how to give a reference of the user and password to the url string. I mean how to inject the content of the user and pass strings into the url String.

Comment: Have you learned about string concatenation? Why do you have the username and password in your URL string and not put them there when you actually make the request?

Comment: Thanks Narendra Motwani he answered my question.

Comment: For starters, don't put passwords in GET requests.

Comment: I know, it's for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [Replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm) function.

This will give you the following code:

```
String url = "http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD";
String USERNAME="123456";
String PASSWORD="123";

url = url.replace("?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD","username="+USERNAME+"&password="+PASSWORD);
```

Although it doesn't seem wise to send a Username and Password in the querystring! If no other option is available be sure to use https so this is not visible for sniffing tools. Otherwise use the [default authentication.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883100/how-to-handle-http-authentication-using-httpurlconnection)

Comment: Why would you do that? Android has URI builder class specifically for this

Comment: If he starts with this full string you will have to cut it first at the '?' so you can use the builder to add the querystring parameters. A String function is always needed. Then it seems shorter to just replace it?

Comment: You'd leave off the question mark for the builder. It adds it. Surely you'd recall whatever method again for different usernames and passwords, so not sure about shorter

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method like below

```
public String getUrl(String Username,String Password){
    String url = "http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?username="+Username+"&password="+Password;
    return url;
}
```

After that you can call this method

```
String URL = getUrl("Username","Password");
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted!

Comment: Your Welcome If this help you then can you please accept my answer